# Как получить каждый n-ый элемент из списка с помощью Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, функциональное-программирование

Предположим, у меня есть такой список:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Можно ли использовать Java Stream API для переноса каждого второго элемента из этого списка, чтобы получить такой список?

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Или, может быть, каждый третий элемент?

```
[1, 4, 7, 10]
```

По сути, я ищу такую функцию, чтобы взять каждый n-ый элемент из потока:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
List<Integer> list2 = list.stream().takenth(3).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list2);
// => [1, 4, 7, 10]
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602425/take-every-nth-element-from-a-java-8-stream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Одним из главных мотивов для введения потоков Java было разрешение параллельных операций. Это привело к требованию, чтобы операции Java Streams, такие как `map` и `filter`, не зависели от положения элемента в потоке или элементов вокруг него. У этого есть преимущество, оно позволяет легко разделять потоки для параллельной обработки. Недостатком является сложность некоторых операций.

Таким образом, нет простого способа сделать что-то такое, например, взять каждый n-ый предмет или сопоставить каждый предмет сумме всех предыдущих предметов.

Самый простой способ выполнить ваше требование - использовать индекс списка:

```
List<String> list = ...;
return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(n -> n % 3 == 0) //3 - каждый 3-ий элемент
    .mapToObj(list::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Примечание от [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev):

> Решение рабочее, но должен заметить, подобное применение стримов - это
>   антипаттерн. Не желательно работать с данными за пределами стрима. Как
>   только появляется идея об обращении к переменной, стоит насторожиться
>   и подумать "Я использую стримы неправильно или стримы тут вообще не
>   подходят?"

---

Используя `Stream.iterate`

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

int skip = 3;
int size = list.size();
// Limit to carefully avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException
int limit = size / skip + Math.min(size % skip, 1);

List<Integer> result = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + skip)
    .limit(limit)
    .map(list::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result); // [1, 4, 7, 10]
```

---

Используя библиотеку [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html)([GitHub](https://github.com/google/guava)):

```
Streams
    .mapWithIndex(stream, SimpleImmutableEntry::new)
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() % 3 == 0)
    .map(Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Используя библиотеку [AbacusUtil](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil):

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
        .filter(MutableInt.of(0), (e, idx) -> idx.getAndDecrement() % 3 == 0)
        .println();
```

---

Используя библиотеку [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) и ее метод `zipWithIndex()`:

```
System.out.println(
Seq.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
   .zipWithIndex()             // This produces a Tuple2(yourvalue, index)
   .filter(t -> t.v2 % 3 == 0) // Filter by the index
   .map(t -> t.v1)             // Remove the index again
   .toList()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> original = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");
List<Integer> intList;
{
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
    intList = original.stream()
        .filter(e -> ((index.getAndIncrement()) % 2 == 0))
        .map(s -> s.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1) // для примера поинтереснее
        .collect(toList());
}
System.out.println(intList); // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]